# Python 3.4 import gcm raise a SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to import gcm as following:

```
from . import gcm
```

And i get:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I tried also called:

```
from gcm import GCM
```

by `pip install python-gcm` but i get the follwoing error:
module' object has no attribute 'GCM

Comment: I think you can use Python client for Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) [here](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm). Do the install as:
`pip install python-gcm`
And import this as:`from gcm import GCM`

Comment: What's the problem? Is it the same one?

Comment: yes, it is the same issue

Comment: why do you use the *relative* import here?

Comment: I think important bit of information is where your gcm library exists, and whether the parent directory of the gcm directory is added to the python's path. Can you provide the info?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the relative import syntax, `from . import gcm`. Instead, put the library where the Python interpreter can find it (via `pip install python-gcm`) and call `from gcm import GCM` in your program.

However, if you still get an error while attempting to import, you should add a comment to the project's [open Python3 import issue thread on GitHub](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm/issues/65) and let them know, since there still appears to be some ambiguity if this bug has been fixed yet or not.

Comment: It is not work!!!!  module' object has no attribute 'GCM  ---  from gcm.gcm import GCM File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible File "C:\Users\frank\untitled1\lib\site-packages\python_gcm-0.1.5-py3.4-win32.egg\gcm\__init__.py", line 4, in <module> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GCM' -

Answer (score 0):

### Make it run temporarily

1. `python-gcm` depends on the `requests` package. Make sure it is installed. Invoke `pip install requests` to install it.
2. Download the ZIP archive of the [master branch](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm/archive/master.zip).
3. Extract the archive into a folder `python-gcm-master`.
4. Patch the file `python-gcm-master/gcm/__init__.py`. Use

   ```
   import gcm

   #GCM = gcm.GCM
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   import gcm

   GCM = gcm.GCM
   ```
5. In this folder create a python file test.py. This file should contain example code from the python-gcm package:

   ```
   from gcm.gcm import GCM

   gcm = GCM(API_KEY)
   data = {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'}

   # Plaintext request
   reg_id = '12'
   gcm.plaintext_request(registration_id=reg_id, data=data)

   # JSON request
   reg_ids = ['12', '34', '69']
   response = gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, data=data)

   # Extra arguments
   res = gcm.json_request(
       registration_ids=reg_ids, data=data,
       collapse_key='uptoyou', delay_while_idle=True, time_to_live=3600
   )
   ```
6. Run this file using `python3 test.py`. Be aware that the example uses `from gcm.gcm import GCM` instead of the default `from gcm import GCM`
7. If an `gcm.gcm.GCMAuthenticationException` is thrown, you can see that it is imported correctly and you need to adjust your `API_KEY`. Adjust the `test.py` file according to your needs.

### Make it run permanently

As far as you tried a relative import, I think you already came across [issue 65](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm/issues/65). Apparently they broke the import mechanism for python3. However, it works per default on python2, but it is buggy with python3. The issue in the issue tracker is still open.